# Adding default pagination to wordpress loop

Tags: theme-development, pagination

I am trying to add default pagination to my Wordpress loop but am unsure where to begin, most guides explain how to create custom numbered pagination. I simply need the default wp pagination. (newer posts / older posts).

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

```
<?php

    $show_posts_number = 12;

    $args=array(
        'meta_key' => '_mcf_homepage',
        'meta_value' => 'Yes',
        'cat' => 6821, // Make the free-bingo cat id
        'showposts' => $show_posts_number
    );
    $top_query = new WP_Query($args);


while ($top_query->have_posts()) : $top_query->the_post();

    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "_mcf_operator-name", true) != '')
        $op_name = "".get_the_title()."";
    ?>

    <div id="" class="grid_s home_list">
            <div class="list_image">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo($op_name); ?>.jpg" />
            </div>
    </div>



<?php endif;  endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: [Perfect example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query). Note, `showposts` is depreciated, you should use `posts_per_page`

Answer (score 0):

As per comments the default pagination would go like this (insert just before `wp_reset_query`)([docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link)):

```
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $top_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
```

Also, as noted in comments, in your query replace `showposts` with `posts_per_page`.